# Word.Application.Selection.Find.Execute does not work with Word 2013

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have the following interop code that has been used with *Word 2010*  successfully:

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
  object readOnly = false;
  object isVisible = false;
  object trueValue = true;
  Word.Document document = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly,
      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
      ref missing, ref isVisible, ref trueValue, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
  object matchCase = true;
  object matchWholeWord = true;
  object matchWildCards = false;
  object matchSoundsLike = false;
  object matchAllWordForms = false;
  object forward = true;
  object format = false;
  object matchKashida = false;
  object matchDiacritics = false;
  object matchAlefHamza = false;
  object matchControl = false;
  object read_only = false;
  object visible = true;
  object replace = 2;
  object wrap = 1;
  wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
  ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward,
  ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
  ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
```

Now I have *Word 2013* installed and the application no longer works. I get this message (translated):

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   ReadWordFiles.exe
>
> Additional information: This method or property is not available,
>   because this command can not be used for reading.

It seems they ripped it out.

What should I use now instead of the former method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe or not, the *error message* means that the file I try to search in is ***read-only.***

If I change the file attribute's, it works without a problem. Logical...

Comment: Believe or not, It took two days to identify that this causing the problem.
Thank you

Comment: @Gowtham.K.Reddy Glad it could help you :)